# Determine convergence or divergence of the following series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> $$\sum _{ n=10 }^{ \infty  }{ (-1)^ n } \frac { n^ 2 }{ \ln(n) }$$

**My attempt**

Since this is an alternating series,

$$\lim _{ n\rightarrow \infty  }{ \frac { n^ 2 }{ \ln(n) }  } $$

diverges. So, the series diverges. Can anyone please verify this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough rep to comment, so I'll write this as an answer. Yes, you're correct.

Since $\lim_n \frac{n^2}{\log n} = \infty$, it follows that $\lim_n (-1)^n\frac{n^2}{\log n} \neq 0$. Thus, the series diverges.

Comment: In the Summation does $n=10$ matters or does not

Comment: Nope, not at all.